# How to prompt Authorize required script on Open Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a template file with a script that needs to be authorized every time the file is duplicated.  I would like the authorization to prompt when the file is duplicated and opened.  How do you for prompt authorization on open?

Comment: The script needs to be authorized by each new user.

Comment: @Cooper Yes, I would like each user to Authorize.  I just want the script to prompt Authorization on open instead of manually running the script and having it prompt Authorization.